# How to find customer with more than 10 purchases in one month period postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

So I have a table list of customer_id and order_date over one year period.
I would like to know how many customer actually made purchases more than 10 times in a month period.
For example, if I purchase 11 times from 15th of October to 15th of November, I would be in this criteria.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `generate_series` to generate the date for each day in your 1-year period, join it to the purchases and use the window function COUNT over a window of 30 consecutive days from the date of the current row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `window function` which calculates for each row the number of order_dates in the past 30 days for the same customer_id.
Then you filter the customers who have more than 10 orders from this list :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT customer_id
     , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date :: date RANGE BETWEEN '30 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS count_last_30_days
  FROM your_table
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id) customer_id
  FROM list
 WHERE count_last_30_days > 10
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I would like to get more explanation about your answer.

Comment: - First, how does syntax WITH list AS work?

Comment: - Second, how does this logic  
count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date :: date RANGE BETWEEN '30 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS count_last_30_days
work?  

Thanks a lot, since I am quite a new SQL user, It would help me greatly to get deeper explanation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I recommend you to read the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) and especially regarding the queries : [2.5. Querying a Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-select.html), [2.6. Joins Between Tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html), [Chapter 7. Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your help! Highly appreciated